# Array of objects in certain cells of a CollectionView

Tags: xamarin

[My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVmfK.jpg)

I have created a food ordering app. Some food items available for order have promotional items. For an example if I choose to order a full pan of chicken it will come with a choice of fries, rice, vegetables, etc. Some items that are ordered do not have promotional items. So, in my shopping cart like in the image I provided above, the items in the cart are displayed in a CollectionView. I'm trying to figure out how to add an array of picker items for each cell in the CollectionView(food item) that has these available promo items. I am getting my data from a database and that part is done but I have no clue how to add these picker controls on the fly when an item in my cart has promo items to choose.

Comment: add a Picker control to your template, and bind it's IsVisible property to your VM array of items, using a ValueConverter to set it to false if the array is empty

Comment: Thank you for your response.  That is a great option but I also forgot to mention that some of the items have a choice of more than 1 promotional item that will really never exceed 5 promotional items. So I guess I can add 5 pickers that are not visible then according to how many promotional items up to 5 I can enable their invisible property so i don't have to set an array

Comment: Are you using CollectionView.ItemTemplate and DataTemplate? You can add any items you want in there and it will show up for each item in the collection view. Please consider including relevant code.